# Standard ways to make a variable low pass filter

Tags: circuit-design, low-pass, standard, synthesizer

I tried out a basic low pass filter on one of my analog synthesizers:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f11bIv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

and this seems to work. I was wondering how I can create a variable low pass filter. I first thought that I would replace the capacitor with a variable capacitor, but I have a hard time finding these at the range of about 470 nF. Then I did replace the resistor with a variable resistor and this seems to work somewhat. But I am wondering if it is just that simple. My question is therefore:

**What is the/a standard way of making a variable low pass filter?** (used for synthesizers.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a digi-pot to make the resistor variable. Then select multiple capacitors that have values that define the filter ranges that work with the resistance range of the digi-pot. Use an analogue mux chip to select which capacitor is switched into the filter circuit at any given time.

Deploy a microcontroller to control the pot and mux. The MCU can also support the user interface of your choice.

Answer (score 2):

One method I have seen used in bass guitar add-on circuits is a PWM modulated R using a CMOS transmission gate.

If you choose the frequency such that it is not audible and vary duty cycle,d then the effect Reff=R/d.

This results in a reduction of **f(-3dB)=1/{2piReffC}**,  but also a rise in output impedance so it must be buffered.

A simple vbl. PWM can be made by offsetting the DC bias input towards Vcc/ or Vcc*2/3 of a CMOS Schmitt Relaxation Osc.

Answer (score 2):

Your varipot approach works "somewhat" because the simple filter you built (one-pole) doesn't have a very steep drop-off.  For the fairly narrow band of the audio signal, what you're trying to do will yield mediocre results.

You're better off making a few higher order filters, and using a multi-position switch to switch between them.

Alternatively, you can buy reasonably-priced switched-capacitor filters (sort of what @TonyEERocketScientist was talking about).  Such devices use the frequency of a square wave clock to set the cutoff.  You would then need to generate a clock signal, maybe with a microcontroller or 555 timer.  For an example part, there's the [MAX7490](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/analog/analog-filters/MAX7490.html)